# Calculating variable in javascript based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, input, onchange

I have the following javascript code:

```js
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
var BetAmount1 = parseFloat($(':input[name="BetAmount"]').val(),10);
var v = '';
if (!isNaN(BetAmount1)){
    v = BetAmount1 * 10;
}
$(':input[name="PotentialGain"]').val(v.toString());
});
```

I have the following two inputs being echoed through PHP:

```php
<input class="defaultText" type="text" name="BetAmount" id="BetAmount">
<input type="text" name="PotentialGain" id="PotentialGain" />
```

When the user inputs or changes a `BetAmount`, I would like to instantly show a calculated `PotentialGain`, which, for example, can be found by multiplying a constant by the specified bet amount entered in by the user.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: That handler should be bound to all INPUT elements? Or just the "BetAmount" INPUT element?

Comment: Use $("#BetAmount") and $("#PotentialGain") for better performance, since both fields have IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
$betAmount.on( 'keyup change', function () {
    var gain = 10 * +this.value;
    if ( isNaN( gain ) ) return;
    $potentialGain.val( gain );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rj64t/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to paid an attention to Knockout.js lib http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html, it's easy to do such thing with this lib and even more!